# How do I determine if my bash terminal window is maximized?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a bash script that maximizes the terminal (`echo -ne '\e[9;1t'`) on start-up and resets it (`echo -ne '\e[9;0t'`) at shut-down which sucks when the script is launched from a terminal that is already maximized. I want to detect if the terminal is already maximized, and if so skip the maximize/reset portion of the script, but I can't find where I can detect if the terminal is maximized in bash. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The same set of escape sequences (see [Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_) has

```
Ps = 1 1  -> Report xterm window state.  If the xterm window
 is open (non-iconified), it returns CSI 1 t .  If the xterm
  window is iconified, it returns CSI 2 t .
```

Your "\e[" is "CSI" in this context.  Using bash's "read -t" for example, you can read the response.

From the comments, I'm reminded that the question is for *maximized*, and suggested that codes 18 and 19 could be used.  However, due to window decorations (title/border) there is no way that the result from 18 would match that from 19.  In discussion, a problem was noted with bash's "read -t" - which I see was not a good recommendation (it appears that bash modifies the stty modes).  Here is an example which would read the given responses, without attempting to use "read -t":

```
#!/bin/bash

get_reply() {
    TTY=$(tty)
    exec </dev/tty
    OLD=$(stty -g)
    stty raw -echo min 0 time 5 2>/dev/null
    printf '\033[%st' "$*" >/dev/tty
    read reply
    stty $OLD 2>/dev/null
    exec < $TTY

    content=$(echo ".$reply" | sed -e 's/^.[//' -e 's/t$//')
    echo "REPLY:$content"
    echo "$reply" |od -bc
}

get_size() {
    get_reply "$1"
    content=$(echo ".$content" | sed -e "s/^.$2;//")
    echo "...$content"
}

if printf '\033]0;%s\007' "Testing" >/dev/tty
then
    get_reply 11
    if [ $content = 1 ]
    then
            get_size 18 8
            get_size 19 9
    else
            echo "** iconified"
    fi
else
    echo "? not a tty" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Because a solution would have to simply read the original size and save it (somewhere), there are simpler ways to read the size.  For example, the stty and resize programs provide the information more easily:

```
$ stty -a |head -n 1
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
```

and

```
$ resize -u
COLUMNS=80;
LINES=40;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

Comment: As hard as I find questioning you on this here... this doesn't seem to answer the question since, unless maximized counts as iconified, this wouldn't distinguish between the maximized and normal sized cases would it? I was just about to suggest that the `PS = 1 8` and `PS = 1 9` might be useful here though.

Comment: Yes, this check seems to check for minimized or not, as opposed to actual state.

Comment: Also, I've tried all kinds of combinations with `read`, and I all ever get in return is "invalid timeout specification"

Comment: yes - PS = 18 vs 19 (saving the size before, and comparing) would help.  PS=19 by itself is not that useful, since the result from PS=18 will never match it (because there is always a window border to account for).

Comment: (non-iconfied vs maximized was merely blunder :-)

Comment: The "-t" option of bash's read expects a number -- see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546644/why-read-t-is-not-timing-out-in-bash-on-rhel (xterm's sample scripts use a more elaborate scheme which is harder to present in these answers - "fonts.sh" for example, in the xterm sources).

Comment: I did eventually figure that out, but I still don't know how to do the read you are suggesting. Anything I do results in no output and error code 1. Can you provide an example of using read in the way you are suggesting?